# How to disable or reduce TooManyRequests 429 cooldown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm developing an app which lookup for barcode online using an API

Everything works fine except one thing...

When i scan too fast i get

```
RestClient::TooManyRequests .... Code 429
```

I have made a rescue to handle this exception

But i get this exception when more than 8 requests happened in less than 1 minute in my case

And This API should receive a lot of barcodes scans per minute

My question here:

How to disable or bypass this exception or even increase the delay of it

It don't make any sense if you have to wait a minute or 2 per 8 scans while you have like 1000 clients who wants to scan in the same time

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the API is enforcing it, you can't disable it. Sometimes APIs will allow you to request a more generous rate limit. You would have to read your documentation or contact the owner of the API to get some clarity.

Comment: Thank you for the guideline you gave me,
as i read the documentation i found it out,

Burst Limits
On top of daily rate limits, API requests are also limited by a burst rate. Ex. for plan FREE, your application is limited up to 6 requests per minute. Requests sent faster than that will be declined with HTTP status 429. In order to regain the access, your application has to wait for the next window period. Think of it the same as the daily limits, but with a much smaller window.